# Is Scrollview best for holding many views in one Activity? Trying to create Tour app so I need to know that

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create tour app in that app Mainactivity Recyclerview contains Images and TextView When I click that it goes  to another activity. In that Activity I'm going to have images,title,description,price,location etc

Here is my question
In the Second Activity can I have scrollView to hold all these things ? or anyother method ? in java

Thank you !!

Comment: Sure, you can use a ScrollView.

Comment: What about NestedScrollView? Can I use that to hold images,title,description,price,location etc

Comment: Thanks bro for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ScrollView is good to handle your content. You may use NestedScrollView to make your UI more user friendly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028718/getting-null-reference-for-viewpager-in-android-ive-attached-my-database-check

Comment: The link you sent is not working. Also, can you select this question as accepted since it answers your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038844/how-to-add-marker-in-maps-when-it-is-intent-to-particular-location-to-intent-ma

Comment: I get "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043178/how-to-do-intent-to-particular-location-in-google-maps-with-marker-on-it

Comment: Check that one, I don't know automatically it keeps on closing

Comment: Help me in that one bro